# Probability distribution of income

Tags: probability, econometrics

I create an agent-based simulation of some economic phoenomenon, and I need to assign each citizen a random income level. I want to select the income level using a probability distribution that approximates the realistic distribution of income in a modern economy. What distribution should I use? Does it make sense to use exponential distribution?

NOTE: I am not looking for actual census data of a certain economy, but for a more general approximation.

Comment: One big issue when using income in models is how to treat the unemployed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Typically lognormal distributions or sometimes pareto distributions are used to model the distribution of income. Here you can find information how well these distrubtions fit real data for Germany, UK and the US:

http://ideas.repec.org/p/wpa/wuwpmi/0505006.html

Here is a proposal to use a generalized lognormal distribution

https://pure.mpg.de/rest/items/item_1586247/component/file_1586246/content

Comment: I agree, log-normal often seems to be a surprisingly good approximation for all sorts of economic variables.  Definitely in this case it would be my first choice.  Exponential istribution woudl rarely be a good fit.

Comment: The real income distributions have (both) tails heavier than lognormal, or may have some intermediate bumps. But I think most income distribution economists (myself certainly included, http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/j.1467-9361.2005.00262.x) have committed a sin of using the lognormal as a very convenient model.

Comment: +1. Welcome, Arne, and thank you for contributing a well-supported answer.

Comment: Also, from here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Properties and here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gini_coefficient it seems that the mu and sigma paramters of the lognormal can be estimated from the mean wage and the gini index, since:
* mean = exp(mu + sigma^2/2)
* gini = erf(sigma)

Comment: @StasK: What about using a log-t distribution, to get both tails heavier than lognormal?

Comment: Unfortunately the second link is not working, http://home.arcor.de not found.

Comment: @AndrásAszódi, thank, I fixed the broken link.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to include heavy tails while maintaining most of the remaining features of the lognormal, might I suggest the [log-Cauchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-Cauchy_distribution) or, if you need finite moments, the log-Student?

Comment: Is there any evidence that such distributions are reasonable descriptions or approximations of actual income distributions?  (Or at least better than a lognormal...)

Comment: Not that I know of; I was just pointing out that there do exist distributions like lognormal but with the heavy tails StasK mentioned. I couldn't reply to his comment, as I don't have the rep on stats.SE yet.

Comment: Well, then, +1 at least for the idea and to give you a start on that rep (you need 50 points I recall).  BTW, welcome to our site!