# Log-Log model errors are not normal

Tags: linear-model, residuals, logarithm

I am trying to model sales as a function of various variables (debt, number of employees, competitors etc.). For this I have transformed both dependent and independent variables using natural logarithm.

The problem is the residuals are not normal as indicated by both their plot and the Shapiro-Wilk test.

I imagine that the log transform can also affect the residuals: could this explain their lack of normality?

Other model stats are looking good, R2 adjusted = 0.92, F test is significant, Resid Std Err = 0.5, and the mean of residuals is 0.

Edit:

Size of dataset: N = 4403; 8 variables in the model: 3 continuous, 5 discrete

[image]

Comment: How big is your data set? Can you show us a Q-Q plot? Rejecting normality is (1) often unimportant and (2) almost inevitable with a big data set.

Comment: Edited the original post. Thank you for your comment!

Comment: 1. *don't* try to interpret a QQ plot without examining the "prior" plots for the fit of the mean and heteroskedasticity (in R residuals vs fitted and scale-location at a minimum), The QQ plot is only interpretable if the fit and conditional variance assumptions are reasonable.  2. If all that's okay and there's no omitted but potentially important covariates/predictors, you might find a log-link gamma GLM (with logged x) is a better fit for the conditional distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some thoughts:

- your residuals are *left-skewed* (the lower/left-hand tail values are smaller/more negative than expected, the upper/right-hand tail values are also smaller/more negative than expected)
- this probably means you are "overtransforming" your data, i.e. a log transform takes a right-skewed distribution of residuals and converts it to a left-skewed distribution (rather than to a symmetric distribution)
- you might try a weaker transformation, e.g. square-root, or run a *Box-Cox* analysis to compare different transformations (`?MASS::boxcox` or `?car::bcPower` in R; if your original data set includes negative values you may have to try one of the alternatives listed at `?car::bcPower`)
- transforming will also affect the fit of your continuous variables (either improving or worsening the fit, hard to say in advance)
- the violation of the assumption of Normality of the residuals may not be a huge problem (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/267078/why-is-skewed-data-not-preferred-for-modelling)); in particular it won't lead to bias, although it may lead to inefficiency/poorly calibrated models ...

Comment: Thank you very much for these considerations. They are very helpful.